# Wordpress WooCommerce API - delete products and images with python

Tags: python, wordpress, woocommerce

The wordpress woocomerce [REST API - Delete a product](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#delete-a-product) doesnt seems to be deleting attached images to a products ?

```
print(wcapi.delete("products/794", params={"force": True}).json())
```

Based on param "force"

*Use true whether to permanently delete the product, Default is false.*

Wonder if there is easier way to delete all products and attached images ?
There is a php function to put on a server [Delete Images after Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997698/delete-images-after-post) but I need to make it over python.

Comment: As an image can be used by different posts or custom posts, you can delete "attachment" post_type (Images) via WordPress Rest API  … Take a loop at: [Python remove all posts and images (media) via Wordpress REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77850567/python-remove-all-posts-and-images-media-via-wordpress-rest-api)